# Quais são os limites de tamanho das variáveis em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variáveis, memory-limit

Gostaria de saber qual o limite de tamanho de variáveis dos seguintes tipos:

- *String* - Qual o maior número de caracteres que posso ter em uma única *string*?
- *Integer* e *Float* - Qual o maior e menor número que pode ser representado?
- *Array* - Qual o maior número de índices que posso ter em um único *array*?
- *Hash* - Qual o maior número de pares (chave:valor) eu posso ter em um *hash*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Como às vezes isso depende da sua arquitetura (32 ou 64 bits), coloquei os limites conforme definidos no código da linguagem (quando existentes):

### String:

- 32 bits: 2**31 - 1
- 64 bits: 2**63 - 1
- Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638622/do-ruby-objects-have-a-size-limit

### Integer:

- Máximo: (2**(0.size * 8 -2) -1)
- Mínimo: -(2**(0.size * 8 -2))
- Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535721/ruby-max-integer

### Float:

- Máximo: normalmente é 1.7976931348623157e+308
- Mínimo: normalmente é 2.2250738585072014e-308
- Fonte: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Float.html

### Array/Hash:

- Não há limite definido. O limite é a quantidade de memória disponível para o processo.
- Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687517/array-size-too-big-ruby

Answer (score 14):

`String` => limite teórico de 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 (32 bits) ou 2<sup>63</sup> - 1 (64 bits). Quero ver alguém conseguir alocar uma *string* deste tamanho.

`Integer` => Em tese Ruby pode ir mudando a representação e ter valores infinitos.

`Float` => Normalmente limitado pela arquitetura. Em geral entre 1.7976931348623158e+308 e 2.2250738585072014e-308.

`Array` => Não existe um limite teórico. Na prática você não consegue usar nem próximo do limite. Em 32 bits há um limite total de memória virtual de 4GB. Você não conseguirá criar um *array* com 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 mesmo que cada elemento contenha apenas 1 *byte* e em Ruby como tudo é referência, isto está longe de ser possível. Em 64 bits se você tiver 2<sup>63</sup> - 1 elementos, precisará muito por baixo (certamente esse volume é bem maior) 250EB (Exabytes). Esquece.

`Hash` => essencialmente o mesmo embora precise ainda mais memória. Mas novamente, não se preocupe tanto com este limite, o limite prático vem primeiro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Por que o limite teórico das strings é calculado como `2^(arquitetura - 1) - 1`? (agora sim!)

Comment: Vc sabe sobre o limite de endereçamento, de como é calculado esse valor, certo? É 63 e não 64 bits porque ele desconsidera o sinal. Isto é usado no sistema operacional (a memória virtual pode até ter valore negativo para identificar se está na RAM ou disco, mas isso é detalhe).  O -1 é porque começa do 0, então o último número não pode ser considerado, é igual a um *array*. É melhor usar um `int` do que um `uint`, números sem sinal podem comportar mais positivos, mas são difíceis de lidar, principalmente quando há interação com outros tipos.